# Convert pdf to monochrome black-and-white via command line

Tags: command-line, printing, pdf, inkscape, ghostscript

I have a 65-page PDF file that has text in a dark grey. (Actual text, not a picture/image of text.) Printing on my B/W printer, the text gets all blurry, because the printer is trying to make it less than black. I can solve this problem page-per-page by importing the pages to inkscape, selecting all paths, clicking on "Black", which converts all colours including the greytones to pure black, and exporting back to PDF.

Is there a way to do these steps in inkscape in the command line (for batch processing)?

Is there a way to achieve the same result (convert pdf to black and white, **1-bit** greyscale) without inkscape?

---

<sub>*Edit.* There are similar questions [on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93959/how-to-convert-a-color-pdf-to-black-white) and [on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/104656/convert-a-pdf-to-greyscale-on-the-command-line-in-floss/164857#164857), which use Ghostscript. However, these only convert the files to greyscale via the option  `-sColorConversionStrategy=Gray`. The option `-sColorConversionStrategy=/Mono` results in the error `Unrecoverable error: rangecheck in .putdeviceprops`. Since my file is greyscale already, these don't solve my problem.</sub>

Comment: Would it necessarily have to be an inkscape command or are other PDF conversion tools also okay? (I don't know how to do it, I'm just trying to improve the question)

Comment: @ByteCommander Other PDF conversion tools would be okay as well.

Comment: Your pdf file, is it *textual* or image (i.o.w. is the text selectable or not)?

Comment: @JacobVlijm It's text, not an image. (It contains a couple of figures, which I don't need to convert to B/W. I care primarily about the readability of the text.)

Comment: See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93959/how-to-convert-a-color-pdf-to-black-white

Comment: @JacobVlijm Thank you for the link. As also the answers say, the command doesn't work with the `Mono` option for Ghostscript, only with `Grey`. My text is grey already, I need to make it black. Those answers unfortunately don't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/249038) over on SuperUser, this can be achieved by converting the PDF to PostScript and back using a redefined `setrgbcolor` command:

```
gs -o <output-file.pdf> -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
-c "/osetrgbcolor {/setrgbcolor} bind def /setrgbcolor {pop [0 0 0] osetrgbcolor} def" \
-f <input-file.ps>
```

Comment: Does not work with gs 9.26. The document remains in colour.

Comment: @XavierStuvw Still works for me with gs 9.50 on embedded text, vector graphics and images. Did you use a PostScript file as input? How are you checking the output?

Comment: Yes, I used a ps as input; would you please add the line that converts the original pdf into a ps for good measure? What do you mean for 'checking the output'? NB My document is scanned book, and each page appears to be an image.

Comment: I just use the "Print to File" option in the "Print" dialog, selecting PS as filetype. I don't know what command this uses under the hood, but I get similar results with `pdf2ps` which seems to use GhostScript and it *doesn't* work with PS files generated by `pdftops` which uses Poppler (leaving colours as they are). The reason I was asking how you check is that I used to use Evince for checking if the conversion from a dark grey to true black worked, but some versions of Evince used to display true black #000000 in PDF files as something like #111111 (presumably to be "screen-friendly").

Comment: If `pdf2ps` works also for you, I'll add this to my answer, but a scanned book should probably be converted to greyscale rather than pure B/W using something like [this answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/164857)...? @XavierStuvw

Comment: no, my text is still gray

Answer (score 8):

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/164857) given at superuser worked for me, I did not get other answers on this question working within 2 minutes. Credits go to goyinux for the original answer.

```
gs \
 -sOutputFile=output.pdf \
 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
 -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray \
 -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceGray \
 -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 \
 -dNOPAUSE \
 -dBATCH \
 input.pdf
```

Comment: no, my text is still gray

Answer (score 3):

This has worked for GhostScript 10, which has apparently added suport for blackening the vectors in 2022:

```
gs \
 -sOutputFile=output.pdf \
 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
 -dBlackText -dBlackVector \
 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH \
 input.pdf
```

Comment: Works even better with `-dBlackText` alone if you are only after true black text. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me in Mint 20.04 to darken PDF text while trying to avoid the relatively heavy Adobe product.

To take a PDF with gray text and make it easier to read:

1. Convert the PDF to individual image files:

   ```
   pdftoppm input_file.pdf output_file -png -rx 300 -ry 300
   ```

   where `-rx 300 -ry 300` is the DPI.
2. Export your PDF pages to image files, and then batch process them.

   Install XnConvert using its [.deb package](https://www.xnview.com/en/xnconvert/#downloads) or using [Flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.xnview.XnConvert). Add the PDF in the first tab. Go to *Add* → *Map* → *Black/White Points*. *White Points* should be higher than *Black Points*. Put them at like *190* and *127* respectively (adjust from there).

   In the output tab use the following:

   - *Filename: yourfilename*
   - *Format: PDF*
   - *Quality: 99*
   - *Multipage: Convert multipage file to multipage file*.
3. Install `gscan2pdf` and open the application. Drag and drop the selected batch of files from the file manager to the vertical bar on the left of the `gscan2pdf` app. *File* → *Save*, select *Downsample* to *150 PPI*, select a name for your new PDF with blacker text.

---

I suspect the Adobe reader approach will work too, but here is a version without the Adobe product. On the upside, XnConvert seems quite flexible and lightweight. On the downside I don't think XnConvert is open source either.

Comment: note that omitting `-png` makes `pdftoppm` significantly faster, in case you don't specifically want a png. Also `-progress` is handy.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a shell script to convert any [pdf to monochrome](https://github.com/agdeva8/monochromed-pdf)
 i.e. to pure black and white. Please check it out and let me know if you face any problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
convert -colorspace GRAY color.pdf gray.pdf
```

Comment: It may cause a visible loss in quality

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am keeping signed document scans in color, but need reprint it without gray noice. For this case works well

```
convert -density 300 -threshold 75% input.pdf output.pdf
```

(based on [the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84711/411221))

Range between 50%-75% works fine in circumstances when you have color scan PDF (text as image) with original resolution 300dpi.

In case of text saved as PDF (not image) you will get huge increasing of output file size.